# General Existence and Uniqueness of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to make sure that I understand the following question. As well as I am having a bit of trouble understand the partial solutions given.

The question is basically, what can we say about the following IVP ?

$$ y'=y^{1/3}$$ with initial value, $y(0)=0$ for $t \ge 0$

I know that the important theorem to be aware of is the theorem about unique solutions depending on continuity of the partial derivative w.r.t to y and existence depending on the continuity of f(t,y) itself.

So what I am seeing initially is that the partial derivative (w.r.t to y) is continuous everywhere expect at $y=0$. and  $f(t,y)$ itself is continuous for all values of $t$.

So does this Imply that we have a solution for all values of t, but we will only have a unique solution when $y \neq 0 $ ?

Solving, using the fact that we have a separable equation gives me,

$$y^{-1/3}dy=dt$$

Integrating both sides,

$$\frac{3}{2}y^{2/3}=t+c$$

$$y^{2/3}=\frac{2}{3}(t+c)$$

$$y^2=[(2/3)(t+c)]^{3}$$

$$y= \pm [(2/3)(t+c)]^{3/2}$$

From our initial conditions we can solve easily for c, to get that $c=0$

that is $y=\pm (2/3)t^{3/2}$

Now here is my first point of confusion, the solution says for both these answers, $t \ge 0$  I think I am just lost in it and even though I understood what the theorem stated, I don't understand its implications.

As well, from initial observation we know $y=\psi(t)=0$ is also a solution.

And the final answer is that $y= \lambda (t)= 0$ if $0 \le t \le t_{o}$ and $\pm[(2/3)(t-t_{o})]^{3/2}$ if $t \ge t_{o}$ Is the reason we have that the second part is only for $t \ge t_{0}$ just to avoid taking square root of negatives?

I am still confused about the final answer. I understand how we found that we could have $\pm [(2/3)(t+c)]^{3/2}$ and y=0 but what I am not understand is how from that we can obtain y=0 if $0 \le t \lt t_{o}$ and $\pm [(2/3)(t-t_{o})]^{3/2}$  if $t \ge t_{o}$? How was this done? It just directly stated this. Mainly, how is it that it went directly to saying 
Can someone please help tie this together for me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your equation is of the form $y' = f(t,y)$ with $f(t,y) = y^{1/3}$.

*Theorem (Short time existence)*: If $f(t,y)$ is continuous at $y_0$, then $y' = f(t,y)$, $y(t_0) = y_0$ has a solution on some interval containing $t_0$.

Your equation satisfies this.

*Theorem (Short time uniqueness)*: If $f(t,y)$ is continuous at $y_0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exists and is continuous at $y_0$, then $y' = f(t,y)$, $y(t_0) = y_0$ has a unique solution on some interval containing $t_0$.

Your equation doesn't satisfy this for $y_0 = 0$, because $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} y^{1/3} = \frac{1}{3} y^{-2/3}$ does not exist at $y = 0$. So you don't have uniqueness of solutions starting with $y_0 = 0$.

If you start at some $y_0 \neq 0$, you do have uniqueness of solutions *for a short time at least*, in other words, *on some time interval containing $t_0$*. After a while, you might reach $y = 0$ on your solution, and uniqueness would fail. This theorem doesn't say anything in particular about *long time uniqueness.*

(Note: There are weaker conditions to put on $f$ in the theorems, but these are simple and work.)

---

*Some intuition for what's going on*:

If you sketch a slope field for $y' = y^{1/3}$, you'll note that there is a constant solution at $y = 0$. Often in such a case, there will be nearby solutions that asymptote to this solution. But in this case, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{3} y^{-2/3}$ (the rate at which the slope is changing) gets too large near $y = 0$, and solutions that start negative actually *reach* this constant solution.

Once that happens, uniqueness is shot: you can switch from the nearby solution $y = \left(\frac{2}{3} t\right)^{3/2}$ that has reached $y = 0$ to the $y = 0$ solution.

In fact, there are uncountably infinitely many solutions: you can stay on $y = 0$ for any distance and then start on one of the $\pm(2/3)^{3/2}(t+c)^{2/3}$ curves.

---

*Note on weaker conditions*:

As mentioned in the section above on intuition, the problem was related to the fact that the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ becomes unbounded (arbitrarily large) near $y = 0$.

A weaker condition in the uniqueness theorem: $f(t,y)$ is *Lipschitz* in $y$. That is, there's some constant $C$ such that $|f(t,y_1) - f(t,y_2)| \leq C |y_1-y_2|$. (In fact you only need *locally Lipschitz*, which I'll leave to you to look up.) This really gets at the issue: $f$ should not be allowed to change *too* quickly, in the sense that secant slopes $\frac{|f(t,y_1) - f(t,y_2)|}{|y_1-y_2|}$ should be locally bounded. The existence and continuity of the derivative guarantees this, so it's a nice simpler-to-state condition to use in the theorem.

A wiki reference to the relevant theorem: [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

---

*Note on why there are uncountably many solutions to $y' = y^{1/3}$, $y(t_0) = 0$*:

$y = 0$ is a solution, as you noticed

$y = \pm[(2/3)(t-t_0)]^{3/2}$ is a solution, as you noticed

But so is

$y = 0$ for $t < T$ and $y = \pm[(2/3)(t-T)]^{3/2}$ for $t \geq T$ (for any $T \geq t_0$, so that $y(t_0) = 0$)

and so is

$y = 0$ for $t > T$ and $y = \pm[(2/3)(t-T)]^{3/2}$ for $t \leq T$ (for any $T \leq t_0$, so that $y(t_0) = 0$)

and so is

$y = \pm[(2/3)(t-S)]^{3/2}$ for $t \leq S$ and $y = 0$ for $S < y < T$ and $y = \pm[(2/3)(t-T)]^{3/2}$ for $t \geq T$ (for $S \leq t_0 \leq T$, so that $y(t_0) = 0$)

*Why are these last three solutions as well?*

The equation $y' = f(t,y)$ is an equation about the derivative of $y$. Both $y = 0$ and $y = \pm[(2/3)(t-T)]^{3/2}$ have the same derivative, namely zero, at $y = T$, so the piecewise function is differentiable with derivative zero there as well, so it must also be a solution to $y' = y^{1/3}$.

In fact, if you think carefully about the fact that the solutions are (on short time scale) unique away from $y = 0$, you'll see these are a complete list of the solutions.

*Another comment on this*:

If two solutions meet, they must have the same slope, because the equation $y' = f(t,y)$ determines the slope based on $t$ and $y$. So if two solutions meet (which precisely means you don't have uniqueness), you can always switch from one to the other as well.

The equation $y' = y^{1/3}$ is a very special situation where we have a whole line $y = 0$ of cases where uniqueness is violated, and this line is also itself a solution. In this case we get this uncountable family of solutions.

Comment: Thank you, but if possible could you just clarify for me, why we have the solutions as t-to,  is it common usage to have y(to)=0?

Comment: @Quality There's nothing special about $y(t_0) = 0$ in general, but for this equation $y(t_0) = 0$ is special because $f(t,y)$ is not differentiable at $(t_0,y_0)$ precisely when $y_0 = 0$. (The reason it's one single $y$ value, and the $t$ value doesn't matter, is because the equation is _autonomous_, i.e. $f(t,y)$ doesn't depend on $t$. This is also just something special about this equation.)

Comment: I see, so is this the reason why the second part of the solution is in the form t-to, for $ t \ge to $ ? because if this wasn't the case it would begin approaching 0?

Comment: I am still not exactly understand, ( I editted my question to explain why). I do appreciate your reply and response, although I hope that the last part is not required for understanding. I am just opening up the question to see if there is any other ideas, and if nothing else I will re accept this

Comment: @Quality I've edited in a comment about this. The reason you can shift from the $\pm[(2/3)(t-t_0)]^{3/2}$ solution to the $y = 0$ solution is because they have the same derivative when they meet. Since the equation $y' = f(t,y)$ is only about the derivative, this works. So you have many solutions: $y = 0$ only, $y = \pm[(2/3)(t-t_0)]^{3/2}$ only, $y = 0$ for $t < T$ and $y = \pm[(2/3)(t-T)]^{3/2}$ for $t \geq T$.

Comment: @Quality I've added additional commentary on this in the answer.